# How to get data-id in list html to javascript in django template?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I'm trying to list several elements and have the possibility to edit them through a modal, I tried to use the data-id property but that way it only works with the first element of the list.

This my Html:

```html
{% for job_title in job_title_list %}
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div style="width:200px">{{job_title.title}}
          <a class="col-xs-1 text-info" data-id="{{job_title.id}}" data-title="{{job_title.title}}" id="update_{{ job_title.pk }}" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModal">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a>    
         </div> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

This my javascript:

```js
//update
        $("#update_{{ job_title.pk }}").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var title = $(this).data("title");
            $("#update_title").prepend(
                "<div id='title_to_update'><label>{% trans 'Nome do cargo' %}</label><input id='job_title' class='form-control' name='title_to_update' value=' ' /></div>"
            );
            document.getElementById("job_title").value = title;

            $("#update_sts").prepend(
                "<div id='sts_to_update'><select class='form-control' id='new_sts' name='new_sts'> {% if l.status == '1' %}<option value='1'>{% trans 'Ativo' %}</option><option value='0'>{% trans 'Inativo' %}</option> {% else %} <option value='0'>{% trans 'Inativo' %}</option><option value='1'>{% trans 'Ativo' %}</option> {% endif %} </select></div>"
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where in your template this JS is, but the problem is that, unless you move this to inside the `for` loop (which I don't recommend), `{{ job_title.pk }}` will have a single value, so this click handler will only get attached to the one element.

Since it seems this ID is the only thing in the JS which depends on the particular `job_title` element, and use `$(this)` to access the things you need that are specific to the clicked-on element you can make this work by removing all reference to the loop variable in the JS, by simply changing the selector. I see two options, both of which should work:

1) Make one that works for all IDs which begin with `update_`:

```
$("[id^=update_]").click(function(){...})
```

2) (likely simpler, and what I would recommend) replace the various IDs with a class:

HTML -

```
<a class="col-xs-1 text-info" data-id="{{job_title.id}}" data-title="{{job_title.title}}" class="update" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateModal">
```

JS -

```
$(".update").click(function(){...})
```

Comment: Thanks bro i will try implement this tomorrow

Comment: Sorry budy, but in this way how to acess values in js script?

Comment: ```javascript
$(".update").click(function(){
      console.log('called');
.
.
.
```
This no execute console.log(), can you help-me, im backend dev and i have some problems with js and html

Comment: Did you change the HTML to include the class, as I showed in the answer? You need the `class="update"` on each of the elements.